# Modifying data from parent scope inside a dispatch queue

Tags: objective-c

According to the Concurrency Programming guide:

> When blocks are added to a dispatch queue, these values must typically be left in a read-only format. However, blocks that are executed synchronously can also use variables that have the __block keyword prepended to return data back to the parent’s calling scope.

I have been altering variables created outside the queue, but I have never specified them with `__block` so I'm wondering just exactly when or why this is needed. Or is it that instance variables are always inherently alterable by blocks, as if they have `__block` assigned to them from behind the scenes?

Update: I should add too that I am using asynchronous queues, while the above says that variables can be altered only in synchronous queues (with `__block`)

Comment: In the [Block Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW1) it states that instance variables are available in blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing an instance variable `iVar` of your class inside a block is interpreted by the compiler as `self->iVar`. Therefore the block captures `self`, which is not modified.

I am sure that the `__block` modifier works also with `dispatch_async`, so this might be a documentation error.

**ADDED**

The following example shows how a `__block` variable might be used with `dispatch_async`:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
__block int total = 0;
printf("address of total: %p\n", &total);

// dispatch some (concurrent) blocks asynchronously:
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    OSAtomicAdd32(5, &total);
});
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    OSAtomicAdd32(7, &total);
});

// Wait for all blocks to complete:
dispatch_barrier_sync(queue, ^{ });

printf("address of total: %p\n", &total);
printf("total=%d\n", total);
```

Output:

```
address of total: 0x7fff5fbff8f0
address of total: 0x100108198
total=12
```

One can see that `total` is copied from stack to heap when the blocks are executed.

**ADDED**

I just found this in the *Blocks Programming Guide*. It explains why it is no problem to use `__block` variables with asynchronous blocks.

> __block variables live in storage that is shared between the lexical scope of the variable and all blocks and block copies declared or
>   created within the variable’s lexical scope. Thus, the storage will
>   survive the destruction of the stack frame if any copies of the blocks
>   declared within the frame survive beyond the end of the frame (for
>   example, by being enqueued somewhere for later execution). Multiple
>   blocks in a given lexical scope can simultaneously use a shared
>   variable.
>
> As an optimization, block storage starts out on the
>   stack—just like blocks themselves do. If the block is copied using
>   Block_copy (or in Objective-C when the block is sent a copy),
>   variables are copied to the heap. Thus, the address of a __block
>   variable can change over time .

Comment: Of course they might be used. Documentation is not saying that you can't! It is just unsafe to use `__block` with ivar objects, because they'll not be retained if they have this specifier.

Comment: @Johnnywho: andrewx asked why the `__block` modifier is not needed for access to instance variables inside the block and I explained that. He also asked if `__block` can be used which asynchronous blocks, contrary to the documentation. I said it can be used and gave an example. So I am not sure why this answer was downvoted. - Of course I might be wrong but I am pretty sure that there is no problem using `__block` variables here. I do not see a case where a variable might not be retained (assuming ARC of course).

Answer (score 2):

Quote from Concurrency Programming Guide is about variables that are created inside a function or method. Variables created inside them are created on the **stack** which holds them as long as function call. In other words, when the function returns, its stack frame is destroyed along with the variables.

Objects in Objective-c are created on the **heap** so they can live after function returns, however when you create line like:

```
MyClass *object = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

You're creating object which will be placed on the heap, but you're also creating variable `object` which holds the pointer to your object in heap. That variable is placed on stack frame of current method/function and will be disposed after it returns. Your object, if you not release it, will not be disposed even though function has ended.

That's why blocks copy parent's scope variables that are referenced inside block. They're copied to block's private memory because they could be destroyed at the end of function call, and as you know, block could be used after that. <strike>That's why you need to use `__block` specifier to inform block to not to copy variable from stack and use it directly. Because this variables can be destroyed when function returns, Concurrency Programming Guide points that only synchronous dispatch should be used in that case, because it will ensure that block is performed before function returns.</strike> **EDIT: As Martin R correctly pointed out `__block`variables are not always used directly from stack. As [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW6) says, they are treated like pointers and their address can be changed from stack when block is copied (like in dispatch). Copied variables are placed in storage that is shared between blocks and function to extend the lifetime of variable. I think that the reason why it is stated that local variables should be used with dispatch_sync is that in non-ARC environment variables are not retained[*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW6), and thus creating jeopardy of using deallocated object. For the same reason I think that you don't use __block before static and instance variables.**

Variables that are **instance variables** or **static variables** don't live on the stack of any function, thus they're not copied by block, and you don't need `__block` specifier. Static variable will live as long as program runs, but instance variable is destroyed when object which holds that variable is destroyed. That's why blocks have another feature - all objects that are referenced inside a block will be retained for lifetime of a block to ensure that object will not be deallocated unexpectedly.

Comment: I do not think that `__block` causes the variables to used from stack directly. Instead, they are copied to the heap if necessary. I have added an example program showing this behavior in my answer. This is also described in the WWDC 2010 Session 206 "Introducing Blocks and Grand Central Dispatch on iPhone".